# Custom made algorithm for access token

Tags: jwt, session-cookies

I want to create custom made algorithm for web access token vs using JWT.
My algorithm will use XOR with secret key in order to encrypt.
so for example : for {username : user, timestamp : 1212121, md5 of the above} I will xor it with secret key and send it to the user.

The benefit for me is that attackers will have hard time to guess how I built the encryption vs well known JWT. So trying to send me a cookie with admin/another user will be harder for him.

My main question is why to use JWT and not creating your own algorithm which will be harder for attacker to reverse engineer ?

Tnx

Answer (score 1):

It's because no algorithm is fully sound; people make mistakes, a lot, in ways that you probably wouldn't have predicted. Then there is the maintainability aspect that even if you're an A grade expert on these kinds of things, you have to maintain that algorithm. And is that really something you want to be doing over providing business value?

Also, the advantage of using well known standards for authorization, encryption, etc. is that they have proven (as far as possible) that they are secure 'enough' for at least the near future and extensively tested as they are used by billions of sites/apps on a daily basis.

So summarizing: it's just not worth the effort, and the probabilty and cost of a mistake is too high..

Answer (score 0):

Using xor with a secret key means that you will not be able to use asymmetric keys, so any client which needs to decrypt the token will have to know the secret, and thus will be able to encrypt tokens as well.

If your client does not need to decrypt tokens, then you can just use opaque tokens, you don't need JWTs. (Or use the [Phantom Token Pattern](https://curity.io/resources/learn/phantom-token-pattern/) if your APIs do need JWTs but clients don't).

If your client does encrypt the token, then any attacker can easily read your solution and it's no longer that secure. Also choosing your own solution because it will be harder for anyone to guess it is security by obscurity and does not add real value (e.g. a hacker could do a research about you and your code and maybe will find this post on SO, which will give her valuable information about your solution).

When you choose standards for security solutions at least you know what are the potential issues, and how to properly address them so your project remains secure. If you choose a proprietary solution, then you will not know the security issues that you have.